# How to deploy gRPC on App engine standard?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-appengine-node

I'm wondering if a gRPC server can be deployed on AppEngine Standard? There are a few old threads mentioned it only works on AppEngine Flexible. Does anyone know if this is still the case?

The app is in NodeJS if that makes a difference...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the official documentation, the way you use gRPC, will depend in your environment. The official ones, supported in gRPC are listed in this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/tutorials), in which, unfortunately, **App Engine Standard is not mentioned, confirming that it's not supported and doesn't work**

I have found that they have a Feature Request opened for this to be checked, that you can access here - confirming the expectations of not being supported: [Features for gRPC Support](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900994).
I would recommend you to leave a comment there and click to star the issue, so you receive updates on it.

Besides that, the framework available for Cloud Endpoints control of API in App Engine can be accessed here (in case you want to check it): [Cloud Endpoints Frameworks](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Flex also doesn't. As far as I know all traffic has to be sent to port 8080. Therefore if you need a gateway and a gRPC server, your out of luck.